# rails: a single simple_form with two unrelated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to use simple_form_for to display a form that contains inputs for creating an instance of model A and separately an instance of model B. I want to have a single submit button for the form. Models A and B are not associated in any way, so simple_fields_for doesn't seem to apply here. Ideally, params would contain two hashes, under the keys A and B, so that each object's fields are grouped together. Is there a way to achieve this using simple_form? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can't do it unless if  `A` and `B` are associated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper:

```
    = form_tag action_path do

      = fields_for :model_a do |a|
        = a.text_field :name

      = fields_for :model_b do |b|
        = b.text_field :name

      = submit_tag 'Submit'
```

Comment: I'd like to still use simple_form_for, it's really convenient.

Comment: Simple form has [simple_fields_for wrapper for fields_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for)