# Submitting two tables/model data with single/two form on one webpage with single submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

My issue is simple, lets say I have two models/tables named 'abc' and 'pqr', both has three columns as 'a','b','c' in abc and 'p','q','r' in pqr. This two models may or may not be related/nested.

what I want to do is to create a *single webpage*. On that webpage I want to create a single form which will submit the **data for two models/table** with single button. May be I will create two form but I want only **one submit button**. How do solve this issue in **ruby on rails.**

As in rails we have one model per table.

Comment: You are probably looking for nested forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` if the two models are related.  Otherwise, if the models are unrelated, see Anton's answer in [rails: a single simple_form with two unrelated models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622709/rails-a-single-simple-form-with-two-unrelated-models) describing how to use the `fields_for` helper to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you something in Ruby side. It is possible to do that with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method.

You can add to

> models/abc.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pqr
```

You can find more information about it here.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html